# Install WampServer next to Bitnami Rubystack?

Tags: wampserver, bitnami

I have Bitnami Rubystack installed and I now would like to install WampServer 2 .

I donwloaded it, and followed the instructions, but when I try to go on `http://localhost` , it's always Bitnami Rubystack which is shown.

How should I do ? Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[BitNami Ruby Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/ruby) uses the 80 port for Apache server. If you want to use the same port for WampServer, stop the Apache server first and then start the WampServer Apache. Refresh your browser to see the changes in the page.